# How do I create a new vector of Trait from vectors of types that implement Trait?

Tags: vector, rust, traits

I would like to create a new vector that contains objects that implement `Trait`, from some vectors I already have which contain those objects.

```
trait Foo {
    //
}


struct Bar {
    i: i32,
}


struct Baz {
    c: char,
}

impl Foo for Bar {
    //
}

impl Foo for Baz {
    //
}
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![Bar{i: 2},Bar{i: 4}];
    let v2 = vec![Baz{c: '2'},Baz{c: '4'}];

    let mut v_all: Vec<Box<Foo>> = Vec::new();

    v_all.extend(v1.into_iter());
    v_all.extend(v2.into_iter());

}
```

This of course gets me

```
<anon>:34:11: 34:33 error: type mismatch resolving `<collections::vec::IntoIter<Bar> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == Box<Foo>`: expected struct Bar, found box
<anon>:34     v_all.extend(v1.into_iter());
```

How could I achieve this, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you have a `Bar`, and you need a `Box<Foo>`, then you need to first box the value, then cast it to a trait object, which looks like this:

```
v_all.extend(v1.into_iter().map(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<Foo>));
v_all.extend(v2.into_iter().map(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<Foo>));
```