# How does one return a vector of `Option` wrapping different types? i.e `vec![Option<i64>, Option<String>]`

Tags: generics, rust, syntax

I have a struct with all fields having an `Option<T>` type. I need some checks done whether such fields does not contain `None` regardless of the value.

Initially I thought of the following:

```rust
struct MyType {
    id: Option<i64>,
    id_str: Option<String>,
    abbrv: Option<String>,
    title: Option<String>,
    // ... Some other fields not necessary to check its `Option` variant
}

impl MyType {
    fn has_essentials(&self) -> bool {
        if self.id.is_none()
            && self.id_str.is_none() && self.abbrv.is_none()
            && self.title.is_none()
        {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

But since I might be a masochist programmer, I thought more of it and it seemed that this can be refactored into two functions, one which returns a `bool` and another that simply returns a vector of cloned `Option<T>`, like the following:

```rust
// The following snippet won't compile as there are a lot of syntax knowledge gaps on my end.
fn get_essentials<T>(&self) -> Vec<Option<T>> {
        vec![self.id.clone(), self.id_str.clone()]
}


fn has_essentials(&self) -> bool {
        self.get_essentials()
            .into_iter()
            .try_for_each(|x|{
                if x.is_none() {
                    Err(())
                } else {
                    Ok(())
                }
            })
            .is_ok()
}
```

I tried the following:

```rust
fn get_essentials<T>(&self) -> Vec<Option<T>>
    where
        T: ToString,
    {
        vec![self.id.clone(), self.id_str.clone()]
    }
```

Since I reckoned that `i64` and `String` implements `ToString`.

And running `cargo check`, the compiler spits out the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                            
  --> madler\src\features\models\molecular_idea.rs:43:8                   
   |                                                                      
38 |     fn get_essentials<T>(&self) -> Vec<Option<T>>                    
   |                       - this type parameter                          
...                                                                       
43 |         vec![self.id.clone(), self.id_str.clone()]                   
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `i64`
   |                                                                      
   = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<T>`                         
              found enum `std::option::Option<i64>`                       
                                                                          
error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted                  
                                                                          
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.       
error: could not compile `madler`
```

Implementing the two functions might also lead to a more readable code when changing what's considered "essential" fields for future development.

I looked into the following links but these doesn't seem to fit the solution I'm looking for:

- [How do I create a new vector of Trait from vectors of types that implement Trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876328/how-do-i-create-a-new-vector-of-trait-from-vectors-of-types-that-implement-trait)
- [How to create a vector of trait objects from vectors of objects implementing the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733463/how-to-create-a-vector-of-trait-objects-from-vectors-of-objects-implementing-the)
- [Vector of objects belonging to a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait)

Thanks for reading and attempting to help.

Comment: You can't return `Vec<Option<T>>` if each `T` might be different. You could use the `ToString` and return`Vec<Option<String>>` or perhaps return trait objects: `Vec<Option<Box<dyn ToString>>>`.

Comment: Also note that `T` is a type _**parameter**_ to `get_essentials`. That means it is chosen by the caller, but you are trying to have `T` be the actual type of each field - which the caller cannot choose because they are fixed.

Comment: That’s the part I failed to understand before. Thanks for pointing that out. I’ll look more into that “`type parameter`”, it’s also on the compiler error as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a vector of mixed value types; you have to convert them to being the same type *somehow*. The simplest possibility is to convert them to booleans:

```rust
impl MyType {
    fn essential_field_presences(&self) -> [bool; 4] {
        [
            self.id.is_some(),
            self.id_str.is_some(),
            self.abbrv.is_some(),
            self.title.is_some(),
        ]
    }
    
    fn has_essentials(&self) -> bool {
        self.essential_field_presences() == [true; 4]
    }
}
```

Note that I've used an array (fixed length) instead of a vector to avoid creating a heap allocation for this otherwise very low-cost code. But vectors are often easier to use and scale better for very large problems, so don't take that as “you must do this”.

The above code isn't that much more useful than just `self.id.is_some() && self.id_str.is_some() && ...` If we're bothering to abstract over the fields at all, it might be nice if we could report which fields were missing, and maybe even do something with the present values. So here's how we might do that:

```rust
fn display_value<T: Display>(value: &Option<T>) -> Option<&dyn Display> {
    // Could also be written: value.as_ref().map(|value| value as &dyn Display)
    match value {
        None => None,
        Some(value) => Some(value as &dyn Display),
    }
}

impl MyType {
    fn essential_fields(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (&'static str, Option<&'_ dyn Display>)> {
        IntoIterator::into_iter([
            ("id", display_value(&self.id)),
            ("id_str", display_value(&self.id_str)),
            ("abbrv", display_value(&self.abbrv)),
            ("title", display_value(&self.title)),
        ])
    }
}
```

There's a lot going on here, but I hope that it's useful as an exploration of what one can do in Rust. **I'm not suggesting that you do exactly this — take it as inspiration for what's possible, and use whatever's useful for your actual problem.**

- `display_value` is just a helper for `essential_fields` takes a reference to one of our fields of any type `T` (as long as it can be “displayed” — `T: Display`) and if the value is present, coerces the reference to a *trait object* reference `&dyn Display` — this means that there is only *one* type returned, “something that can be displayed”, using function pointers internally to figure out *how* to display that value.
- `essential_fields` calls `display_value` on each of the fields, and pairs it up with the field's *name* for later display purposes. The return type is an *iterator*, because that is convenient to work with later and is a good abstraction boundary, but it's actually implemented using an array just like in the previous function.
- `-> impl Iterator<...>` means “I'm returning something that implements the trait `Iterator`, but not telling you what that concrete type of iterator is”. This way, the implementation type is kept hidden and can be changed freely (e.g. if this struct gains some sort of dynamic list of “fields” and now this should be iterating over that instead of hardcoding).
- Using `IntoIterator::into_iter([...])` instead of `[...].into_iter()` is a temporary workaround for a Rust compilation backwards-compatibility constraint that can be removed once the [Rust 2021 language edition](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html#intoiterator-for-arrays) is available, which should be in just a couple months.

Now that we have this function, we can use it:

```rust
impl MyType {
    fn report_missing(&self) -> bool {
        let mut any_missing = false;
        for (name, maybe_value) in self.essential_fields() {
            match maybe_value {
                None => {
                    any_missing = true;
                    println!("{}: missing", name);
                }
                Some(value) => {
                    println!("{}: present ({})", name, value);
                }
            }
        }
        any_missing
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyType {
        id: Some(123),
        id_str: None,
        abbrv: Some(String::from("XYZ")),
        title: None,
    };

    x.report_missing();
}
```

[This code on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59843962c71ef9d3de91f48680094004)

Comment: Your answer’s perfect! Like your hair!  Thanks for an elaborate answer. 

You even augmented the solution I’m looking for. It’s better for error handling codes to “know” what fields were missing. Also, I didn’t know the syntax is `Some(val as &dyn trait)`, other syntax I tried but didn’t post here since it clutters my post perhaps, is `vec![self.field.clone() as ToString]`, with a return type of `Vec<Option<dyn ToString>>`.

Thank you very much, I hope I can return a favor someday ‍♂️

PS. You also increase my understanding with setting a type on trait `Iterator`